# Histogram issues between different column datasets

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have a CSV that I'm extracting different columns of data from and reading into a function where I'm creating a histogram. The problem I'm having, my histogram is correct for data in one column and doesn't show the right thing for data in a different column. For example, I have a column that contains ages, my histogram works perfectly on this but I have another column that contains populations (larger number compared to age) and the histogram only shows me the number of rows in the column. When I print the Numpy array, it prints out the same as the age data. The only difference that I can see between the two columns, the age column has over 10k rows compared to 558 population rows and the population numbers are 5-6 digits compared to 1-2 digits for age.

Age column (these work in histogram):

```
82
50
53
67
26
56
50
26
60
26
59
54
25
53
52
67
22
55
57
84
55
74
67
70
59
62
32
```

Populations Column (histogram represents the number of values in the Population column).

```
43191
73901
38247
98266
66781
62075
30444
96109
40497
37964
40822
40599
28360
24949
34969
49455
18128
34586
37489
48177
22061
35218
53745
97493
39764
16193
65818
53285
```

My function is:

```py
def histogram(column_data):
    plt.title(col_name)
    df = column_data.to_numpy()
    af = df.reshape(-1)
    plt.hist(af)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting behavior. I also saw it on the first run (i.e. no plot). Once I used `bins` inside my plot command the problem went away. It likely has to do with the relative sparsity of your population data relative to the quoted precision, just as you surmised.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p

pop= [43191,73901,38247,98266,
66781,62075,30444,96109,
40497,37964,40822,40599,
28360,24949,34969,49455,
18128,34586,37489,48177,
22061,35218,53745,97493,
39764,16193,65818,53285]

dat= np.random.rand(1000) # less sparse data

p.figure (figsize=(10,3))

p.subplot(131)
p.hist(pop)
p.subplot(132)
p.hist(pop,bins=100);
p.subplot(133)
p.hist(dat, bins=100);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this. My graph is only showing 0.0-3.0 on the x axis and 0-250 on the y axis. I do have a few bars in the graph but they're all clustered around 0.0-0.3 and spike up to maybe 275. The data input is the same that I showed you in my original post. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure, the x-axis should be 0..100k. You can also specify the bins as a list rather than a number of bins. If you have the same data as I copied from your question, then the y-axis should be smaller. You only have 28 data points listed. So even if you had a single bin, it couldn't be higher than 28.

Comment: Check the dimensions (shape) of what you pass to hist. It has to be a single list, not 2D. `reshape(-1)` infers the dimension, so you might have something different from what you think you have.